# Get event or notification when user click in taskbar/dock icon in Qt application

Tags: qt, taskbar, dock

I'm developing an application in osx, windows, linux

I want to make feature like skype. when user click close windows, application not exit but hidden. When user click appicon on dock or taskbar, my mainwindow will re-open again.

How do I get a notification or filter events to known when user click on app icon?

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to prevent your application window from closing when you hit the "close window" button. Assuming, that you use `QMainWindow`:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    // .. constructors, etc.
    // ..
protected:
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *)
    {
        // Do not close, but hide the window.
        hide();
    }
};
```

Qt has the dedicated class to handle the task bar icons - `QSystemTrayIcon`. So, the simple application would look like:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MainWindow mw;
    QSystemTrayIcon tray; // needs an icon.

    // Show the main window when user activates the tray icon.
    QObject::connect(&tray, SIGNAL(activated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)),
                     &mw, SLOT(show()));
    tray.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: thank you vahancho,
I found using lower() instead of close() for my application can re-active when user click it on taskbar.
But QSystemTrayIcon bring a new feature for my application. thank you

Comment: Your use of `closeEvent` is wrong. This method merely notifies you that a window is going to be closed, you can't override that action. If you want to prevent a window from closing, you must reimplement the `event` method. For events that you wish to drop, return `true` and don't call the base class's `event` method.

Comment: @KubaOber, the usage isn't wrong, and I can override it. Even docs say: "You can reimplement this function to change the way the widget responds to window close requests. For example, you can prevent the window from closing by calling ignore() on all events."

Comment: @vahancho Ah, you're right, I forgot about the `ignore`. But you didn't call it, and you must! That achieves the same as reimplementing `event`.

Comment: This may work on windows and Linux (dunno), but on the mac the dock icon is a different animal than the "System Tray Icon" (aka a menu bar widget). When I try this on the mac, it doesn't work when clicking the dock icon.

Answer (score 0):

This should be helpful:

```
 void setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(bool quit)
```